# read attribute value within a attribute using XPathNavigator

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

This is how my xPathNavigator looks like:

```
<mux:Column Name="id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Id" Property="Id" DataType="s:String" xmlns:mux="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenter/Common/UI/Views/GridView" />
```

I want to read the value of Path in the DisplayMemberBinding attribute.

This is what i have tried:

```
xPathNavigator.GetAttribute("DisplayMemberBinding", "") //Gives me {Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}

xPathNavigator.GetAttribute("DisplayMemberBinding/Binding/@Path", "") //Gives me empty string
```

How do i get to the value of Path in DisplayMemberBinding attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
xPathNavigator.Evaluate
  (@"substring-before(substring-after(@DisplayMemberBinding, 'Path='),
                     ',')"
  );
```

Of course, you need to cast the result to `string`.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:mux="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenter/Common/UI/Views/GridView">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "substring-before(substring-after(@DisplayMemberBinding, 'Path='),
                    ',')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<mux:Column Name="id"
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}"
Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Id"
Property="Id" DataType="s:String"
xmlns:mux="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenter/Common/UI/Views/GridView" />
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
Id
```